# How to instance an object with field values

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to instance lines and have their length be dictated by an attribute. However, you cant plug a field into the length value.

[image]

How would I be able to accomplish this? I'm going to be manipulating the line itself, so I can't just use a scaling of the instance. It needs to be here. I realize it is then technically not an instance. But that's what I would like to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot instance different lines. This is because the instance object should have the same object data. You can scale and rotate instances independently, but data inside the instance will be linked to each other until you realize instances, so that they will be converted from instances to geometry.

So, you can:

1. Scale instances of line.

[image]

2. Realize instances and then move points inside the line

[image]

I've used random value as an example, but you can use any value

Comment: Yes, #2 has allowed me to achieve what I needed. Thanks again Crantisz