# Randomize value in geometry node particle instance?

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, instances

I am new to geometry nodes so please bear with me if this doesn't make sense. I have an object that is covered in particles via geometry nodes. Each node is an instance of another object that itself is created with geometry nodes. I am trying to randomize a certain value that controls an aspect of the instance object for each instance of it so that they are different. The value I need to modify is early in the instance object's node tree. Every solution I've seen just uses a set position node after realizing the instances to modify the geometry, but I need to change an arbitrary value in the instance object that isn't as simple as moving points. How do I accomplish this?

To be more specific, the instance object is built as a curve that is randomly bent via a noise texture, then geometry is built off the curve. I need the noise texture W to be different for each instance.

Comment: This is quite frequently asked question. You cannot instance different objects, but you can extrude it after:  [How to instance an object with field values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260354/how-to-instance-an-object-with-field-values)

Comment: Sorry, but currently there is no other way to do this. Post another question with your blend file (blend-exchange.com) to see how we can apply this workflow in your case.

Comment: I would like to know this also. Is there still no solution to give random values to instance object trees that are created by geometry nodes inside geometry nodes?